# How to check if a database client is installed in C# before using an action

Tags: c#, database-connection

Just made a windows forms application that at some point when a button is clicked it tries to open a connection to a Terada database (or it can be an Oracle database, or what ever database).
The thing is that the application can be used on computers which don't have the client for that database installed therefore when clicking that button a huge error message appears("Cannot load file or assembly..."). 
All I need to change is to first put on my buttons a verification which to check if the database client is installed but I do not know how to do that check...
A forced way was first to check if the .dll file which I used for my project (as a .Net reference) exists on that computer. But I think a better way may exists.

Any hints?

Many thanks in advance, Bogdan.

Comment: You could always catch the exception thrown.  This is a case where you *know* an Assembly Load exception may occur, and so you can take steps to mitigate the ugly error message and do something more aesthetic.

Comment: What is the database you have to check for ? Normally you can search registry and see if database is installed.